# How to make a proxy for my backend for my angular app during the dev?

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-routing

I'm trying to make sure that every browser call to an URL that is inside the "api" path is redirect to another (dev) server.

So it would mean that when my angular app is requesting :

https://localhost:4200/api/some/feature --> https://localhost:7276/api/some/feature should be requested

This has to take all the sub-folder of /api and also forward the GET attributes.

I've found this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) which seems to do exactly what I'm asking.

I've created the proxy.config.json:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:7276/",
    "secure": "true",
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

modified the angular.json:

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "web:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "web:build:development",
      "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.json"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

and restarted everything:

```
ng serve
```

Now when my angular service try to request `/api/dashboard`, it still fails.

On the browser, I get the following error:

```
 GET http://localhost:4200/api/dashboard/ 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

With a second error with the given value:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 504,
    "statusText": "Gateway Timeout",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/api/dashboard/",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/dashboard/: 504 Gateway Timeout",
    "error": "Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:4200/api/dashboard/"
}
```

In my `ng serve` console, I get this:

```
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/dashboard/ to https://localhost:7276/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

My understanding is that it returns ANYTHING that match the /api/* to the same URL, not adding again the same initial sub path?

I can't find how to just change the host, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run development server on port 7276 of localhost?..